# Sprockets 4 and possibility to pass stylesheets folder handling to dart sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets, ruby-on-rails-7, rails-sprockets

Is there anything in Sprockets 4 to use like [Propshaft has](https://github.com/rails/propshaft#usage)?
`config.assets.excluded_paths`

```
You can however exempt directories that have been added through the config.assets.excluded_paths. This is useful if you're for example using app/assets/stylesheets exclusively as a set of inputs to a compiler like Dart Sass for Rails, and you don't want these input files to be part of the load path. (Remember you need to add full paths, like Rails.root.join("app/assets/stylesheets")).
```

So it can be used together with Dartsass-rails [Configuring Builds](https://github.com/rails/dartsass-rails#configuring-build-options) and therefore everything under stylesheets asset pipeline handled by dart sass?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

1. when some specific css files not set for `config.assets.precompile` (then sprockets not handles them);
2. use dartsass for those extra files:

```
Rails.application.config.dartsass.builds = {
      "application.scss"    => "application.css",
      "example.scss"        => "example.css"
    }
```

3. in `manifest.js` is added build folder, file content:

```
// app/assets/config/manifest.js

//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.js
//
//= link_tree ../builds
//
```

So the asset pipeline works like this: dartsass compiles scss files to css and puts in `/build` folder and sprocets uses it.